# How to make a data-bound combo box display (like a DisplayMember) a concatenated string?

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

I have a first name and a surname as separate columns in a table. If I bind a combo box to a query and set DisplayMember property to "Name" then each person a table is represented in a combo box by its name. How do I show each person's full name (built from concatenating 2 columns) in a single comb box item in this case?

Answer (score 2):

(I'm not sure if this works in winforms, but I'm using this a lot in in ASP.NET):

Add a new property to your entity class, which is used for databinding (concatenates the other properties), e.g:

```
public string DisplayName
{
  get { return this.FirstName + " " + this.LastName; }
}
```